# Modify some elements in 2D python list

Tags: python, list, 2d, element

My list looks like this:

```
board = [ [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0] ]
```

How can I modify some of the elements?
E.g.: the first element in each row = 0. I want to replace them with fives.
So my list would look like this:

```
board = [ [ 5 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 5 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 5 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 5 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 5 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 5 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 5 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
      [ 5 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a specific cell of a 2D array by doing `board[r][c]`, where r is the row and c is the column. For replacing the first column with 5's, you could do:

```
for row in board:
    row[0] = 5
```

This iterates over every row in `board`, and sets the first item in each row to 0.

Comment: And if I get 2 numbers by input and only want to change 1 element?  `r=int(input("row: "))  c=int(input("column: "))`  E.g. r=2 and c=6. So I want board[2][6] to be changed.

Comment: If you want one specific cell to be changed, you can do `board[2][6] = newValue`. Replace `newValue` with the value you want to set there.